# C++ uses the default copy constructor even though the user defines one with a template?

Tags: c++

After a whole day of bug tracing in C++ yesterday I reduced my problem to this:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  virtual void id() { std::cerr << "This is A\n"; }
};

class A1 : public A {
public:  
  virtual void id() { std::cerr << "This is A1\n"; }
};

class A2 : public A {
public:
  virtual void id() { std::cerr << "This is A2\n"; }  
};

template <class T> class jp {
public:  
  T* ptr;  
  jp<T> () { ptr = 0; }  
  jp<T> ( T a ) {
    std::cerr << "Recording address\n";
    ptr = &a;
  }  
  template <class S> jp<T> ( const jp<S>& s ) {
    s.ptr->id();
    ptr = s.ptr;
  }
  /* surely the above template defines "jp<T> ( const jp<T>& s )"
   * but the behaviour is different when it is duplicated as follows *

  jp<T> ( const jp<T>& s ) {
    s.ptr->id();
    ptr = s.ptr;
  }  

  */
};

int main() {

  A a;
  A1 a1;

  jp<A>  jpa1(a);    // make a jp<A>
  jp<A>  jpa2(jpa1); // copy constructor 
  jp<A1> jpa3(a1);   // make a jp<A1>
  jp<A>  jpa4(jpa3); // copy constructor 
  jp<A1> jpa5(jpa3); // copy constructor 

}
```

I have defined a copy constructor haven't I?  It is

```
template <class S> jp<T> ( const jp<S>& s )
```

in the special case when T equals S.  Assuming this there should be 5 lines of output, but I only get three:

```
Recording address
Recording address
This is A1
```

Uncommenting the section which repeats the already defined constructor (but without a template) gives the five lines of output I was expecting

```
Recording address
This is A
Recording address
This is A1
This is A1
```

Please could someone explain? I have read Stroustrup several times and never expected this! what else similar should I know about that I wasn't told?;)

The class A2 is there only to indicate that A might have many subclasses and it is not a trivial matter to duplicate code for each of them.

Thanks!

Comment: Just an FYI. Use of `jp<T>` is redundant use of `T` inside the class. You can use just `jp`.

Answer (score 9):

> I have defined a copy constructor haven't I?

No, you have not.  A copy constructor is never a template.  What you have defined is a constructor that allows you to construct a `jp<T>` from any `jp<S>` (i.e. (`jp<int>` from a `jp<double>`)

Since you have not actually defined a copy constructor the compiler makes one for you and since that wins in overload resolution you never see

```
template <class S> jp<T> ( const jp<S>& s )
```

get called.

Comment: Well clearly this is the behaviour I get, but I am surprised and I'd be interested to know what the standards say about this.  To be more precise I have defined a constructor using a template that constructs a jp<T> from any jp<S> EXCEPT in the special case when T=S. It's a bit like defining int myfunc(int i) which works in all cases except when i=0. I had no idea that that's how templates work.

Comment: "I had no idea that that's how templates work." - well, reading a good book or the standard itself should alleviate that...

Comment: @user2444353 really what this is analogous to is `void foo(int i) {} template<typename T> void foo(T t) {} foo(10);`.  Without the language in the standard that the non template version wins in overload resolution this would be ambiguous.  That would be a shame if it was as you should be able to add an overload without causing an error.

Comment: OK I live and learn - thanks to all!  I did read Stroustrup (whether this is a "good book" I will leave to Jesper to decide) and it does say functions take priority over templates in overloading.  But I didn't understand this to mean invisible functions that I didn't write take priority over templates that I did write... hey ho...

Comment: @user2444353 Yeah, the copy and move are special cases as they are never a template, because of that rule if you don't make one the compiler makes one for you.  It's a constructor corner case ;)

Comment: @user2444353 and you can explicitly make a copy constructor forward to your templated constructor, if that's the behavior you want.

Comment: @DrewDormann thanks! that is exactly what I want but I was unable to find a way of coding it.  Can you enlighten me?

Comment: @user2444353 ask a new question.  Good luck!